# Custom control property as enum

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have a custom control which is a combination of textbox and button (a search control). One of its attribute defined is used to identify its position (whether in Master or Content page so that we make the search settings) that is ***PageName***. Initially this was declared as string property as:

```
public string PageName
{
    set;
    get;
}
```

But since we had some issues with case sensitivity. We changed this as enum, so that users will not enter any random things avoiding the exceptions. So this is now changed to:

```
public enum PageNameProperty { MasterPage , SearchResultsPage, MLIPage };

public PageNameProperty PageName
{
   set;
   get;
}
```

But now we are getting the error as :

**Method not found:'Void UI.SearchTextBox.set_PageName(System.String)'.
 Inner Exception (Level 1)**

Note: Now i cannot force users to change this to PageName.Master or anything else, since they cannot modify the code for current release but can only install our control, so the projects would refer the new DLLs.

I need some solution apart from replicating the property type back to string before the current release.

Please help.

Comment: are you declaring enum within the class ? If so than you should declare out of the class and later you can Accept as a Class Field or Method Parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You changed the signature (return type for instance) of a property. Calling code will fail as they won't find the signature they are expected.

You should keep the original property, mark it as obsolete, and create a new one like this :

```
[Obsolete("User PageName2")
public string PageName {
{
 get { return PageName2.ToString(); }
set { PageName2 = (PageNameProperty )Enum.Parse(typeof(PageNameProperty), value);
}

public PageNameProperty PageName2 { set; get; }
```

This will keep compatibility with former use, while incitating the use of the new one.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Can't there be a solution to keep PageName as it was? Since this control is used by other microsites which cannot change their code in current quarter release. And we need to incorporate these changes.

Comment: In fact, signature of PageName has not changed, only implementation has changed. "Legacy" calls will still works. Only "new" calls will use the PageName2 property. And if "PageName2" is not an acceptable name, you can cheat a bit, using another meaningful name "ContainerPage", "ParentPage", or "TheAnswerIs42"

Comment: Yes will try this. But We have made something like this to overcome null string issues(String.Compare(PageName, "Master", true) == 0)

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like this?:

```
public enum PageNameProperty { MasterPage , SearchResultsPage, MLIPage };  
private PageNameProperty pageName;

public PageNameProperty PageName 
{ 
   get
   {
       return pageName ?? PageNameProperty.MLIPage;
   }
   set
   {
       pageName = value;
   }
}
```

Comment: Actually the set PageName method is the problem. get works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply validate the values to ensure they are using a valid string

private string _pageName = null;

```
public string PageName
{
    set 
    { 
        if (value == null)
           throw new NullReferenceException();
        if (!(new string[] { "master", "content" }.Contains(value.ToLower()))
           throw new InvalidOperationException();

        _pageName = value; 
    }
    get
    {
       return _pageName;
    }
}
```

At design time, this would give the client an error stating that they entered an invalid value.